# Change color of label with if statement

Tags: swift, string, int

I want to change my color of the label if the string i < 0 red. My first problem is to make from a string a int. I tried to do this but i seems not to work. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type
>   '([String])'

Please help.

```
var percent_change_24hArray = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

        let PercentInt = Int(percent_change_24hArray)

        if PercentInt < 0 {
           cell.procentLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        }

        cell.procentLabel.text = "\(percent_change_24hArray[indexPath.row])%"

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use

```
let PercentInt = Int(percent_change_24hArray[indexPath.row])
```

Now the integer you receive is an optional since not all strings can be converted to a integer. You either know as the developer that this can actually never happen in which case you should add a `!` to the end of the line. If it *can* happen you have to safely unwrap the optional using an `if let` structure that fits your need.

Comment: Of course this assumes that there is exactly one row for each element in the `percent_change_24hArray` array.

Comment: Thanks, but i have a different problem now. It says that the value is nil but the value isn't nil because the `cell.procentLabel.text = "\(percent_change_24hArray[indexPath.row])%"` says its for example -17.

Comment: Use `if let PercentInt = Int(percent_change_24hArray[indexPath.row]), PercentInt < 0 {...}`

Comment: @Danjhi you have to deal with the resulting optional. Either look at  Annjawn's comment or the updated answer.